Invalid argument errno 22 in socket programming (recv() function)
I'm writing a function to receive data from a socket, store it in a buffer, return the number of bytes that I read, and do some other checks. I could not debug it for a couple of days.
Unit test:
#define BUFFSIZE 2

void
test_handle_read_socket() {
    /* Arrangement */
    struct conn sender;
    int sockfd[2];

    if (socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sockfd) == -1) {
        perror("Failed creating pair sockets.");
        return;
    }

    // int flags = fcntl(sockfd[0], F_GETFL, 0);
    // fcntl(sockfd[0], F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    // write "123" to the pipe.
    sender.pfd.fd = sockfd[0];
    send(sockfd[1], "123", 3, 0);

    eqint(2, handle_read_socket(&sender));
    eqnstr("12", sender.client_buff, 2);
    eqint(1, handle_read_socket(&sender)); // Tag: The problem, return -1 instead of 1
    eqnstr("3", sender.client_buff, 1);

    /* Teardown */
    close(sockfd[1]);
    close(sockfd[0]);
}

Implementation:
struct conn {
    struct pollfd pfd;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    char client_buff[BUFFSIZE];
    char server_buff[BUFFSIZE];
};



int
handle_read_socket(struct conn *client) {
    int total_read = 0;
    int readsize = 0;

    while (1) {
        readsize = recv(client->pfd.fd, client->client_buff + total_read,
                        BUFFSIZE - total_read, 0);

        if (readsize > 0) {
            total_read += readsize;

            if (total_read == BUFFSIZE) {
                // Buffer is full.
                break;
            }
        } else if (readsize == 0) {
            // client closed connection.
            if (errno == EOF) {
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                // An error happened.
                LOG_ERROR("Something unpredictable happened.");
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            // Client has no data(non blocking).
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                break;
            }
            // An error happened.
            LOG_ERROR("Could not read from client and Error happened.")
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return total_read;
}

When it loops the first time (tag in unit test), recv() returns 1 which is right and puts char '3' in the buffer, but the second time recv() returns -1 and sets errno to 22 which is my problem.
(setting the file descriptor to non-blocking mode does not affect it)

22 is EINVAL.,..

@Joshua yes i have search it and  still don't know how to fix it, I don't understand the problem

I believe your problem is here:
    } else if (readsize == 0) {
        // client closed connection.
        if (errno == EOF) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            // An error happened.
            LOG_ERROR("Something unpredictable happened.");
            return -1;
        }
    }

In particular, the second time handle_read_socket() is called, it will call recv() and recv() will return 1, as expected; but then handle_read_socket() will call recv() a second time (because total_read != BUFFSIZE) and this time recv() will return 0 to indicate EOF (because the server has closed the TCP connection after sending all three bytes), and that causes the above code to unhelpfully return -1/error even though it has read one byte of valid data already.
As a fix, you might change the code to something more like this:
    } else if (readsize == 0) {
        // client closed connection.
        if (total_read > 0) break;  // so caller can handle the received data!
        return -1;  // react to no-data+EOF by returning error
    }

... that way the fact that (some valid data was read) will be reflected in the return-value as you expected.  If handle_read_socket() was then called a third time, recv() would return 0 (again) on the first try, and that is when handle_read_socket() would usefully return -1 to indicate a problem.
ps. I think the EINVAL value reported by errno is a red-herring... errno only gets set to a meaningful value when a system call returns an error-code (e.g. -1), and in this case recv() is never returning an error-code (note that recv() does not consider 0/EOF to be an error so recv() won't set errno when it returns 0!).  So EINVAL is probably leftover from some previous/unrelated system call earlier in the program's execution.

I replaced it with your code but it did not work. According to man 2 read
which recv() man page refers to, on EOF it return 0. I have printed readsize
variable in first loop it return 1 and in scond one -1 and I did not close the
connection (closed in tear down) it does not go inside if(readsize == 0)
condition.

@Saeedou if you can modify your posted code so that I can copy-and-paste it into a test.cpp file and then do a g++ ./test.cpp ; ./a.out to test it locally, I might be able to troubleshoot it better -- without being able to reproduce the problem locally I can only guess at the problem, but if I can reproduce it I can verify as well.

Problem solved. When I mock recv() I gave it wrong arguments. it was read() and when I changed it to recv() i forgot flags argument. Thank you.
